# Using AngularJS in Jasmine tests with Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am using Jasmine with Karma to write a test for an Angular 1.5.7 application.

How should I refer to AngularJS from either the `karma.conf.js` file or the `test-main.js` file, to ensure it is available to my test?

I can currently run unit tests OK, but when a file referred to by the test refers to AngularJS (i.e `import angular from 'angular'`) AngularJS cannot be found, indicating I need additional configuration to get it to work.

I am transpiling to ES5 using babel, and imports are converted to RequireJS AMD.

The error is:

```
 ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for /base/angular.js!'
```

If I add AngularJS to the paths section of `test-main.js` then I get a different error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_angular2.default.module')
```

If I remove the `import angular from 'angular';` from the test target statement then I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
```

My `test-main`:

```
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;
var allTestFiles = [];

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
        allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
    }
});

var cdn = 'http://localhost:55635/modules/';

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base',

    initialRequire: [],

    globals: {
        'es6-promise': '3.2.1',
    },

    paths: {
        'lodash': cdn + 'lodash/2.4.1/lodash'
    },

    shim: {},

    deps: allTestFiles,

    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

My `karma.conf.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(config) {
    'use strict';
    var cdn = 'http://localhost:55635/modules/';
    var basePath = path.dirname(__filename);

    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: [
            'requirejs',
            'jasmine'
        ],
        files: [
            {
                pattern: cdn + 'my-lib/version/my-lib.js',
                included: false
            }, 
            {
                pattern: 'test-transpiled/**',
                included: false
            },
            /**
             * This is needed because PhantomJS does not support window.Promise.
             */
            'node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
            'dist/artifacts/my-lib.js',
            'test/unit/test-main.js',
        ],
        proxies: {
            '/cdn/': cdn
        },
        exclude: [],
        preprocessors: {},
        reporters: ['dots'],
        colors: true,
        autoWatch: false,
        singleRun: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include:

```
'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
'node_modules/angular*/*.js',
```

in your files array in karma.conf.js?

```
files: [
            {
                pattern: cdn + 'my-lib/version/my-lib.js',
                included: false
            }, 
            {
                pattern: 'test-transpiled/**',
                included: false
            },
            /**
             * This is needed because PhantomJS does not support window.Promise.
             */
            'node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
            'dist/artifacts/my-lib.js',
            'test/unit/test-main.js',

            'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
            'node_modules/angular*/*.js',
        ],
```

That was the way I found to include all angular dependencies in karma config.

Hope that helps!